# Is AndroidHttpClient thread safe

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I was wondering, whether is [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) thread safe, as this is not being mentioned in documentation. Means, a single instance of `AndroidHttpClient` can be shared among multiple threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is thread safe.

`AndroidHttpClient` is a special implementation of `DefaultHttpClient` which is pre-configured for Android. It registers the `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` which allows thread safe HTTP access via a managed connection pool. `AndroidHttpClient` also applies reasonable default settings for timeouts and socket buffer sizes. It also supports HTTPS by default.

You can find the source code [**here**](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java/?v=source).

Answer (score 2):

It is Thread safe according the code, since it uses

```
ClientConnectionManager manager =
                new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
```

as per [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java)

The only drawback to this is that it's Api level 8 and above (2.2.x)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's thread safe. Also, be sure to use the factory method:

```
newInstance(String userAgent, Context context)
```

when using it with HTTPS to ensure caching of SSL sessions.