# Can I use a single AndroidHttpClient instance for multiple calls simultaneously

Tags: android, apache, android-networking, apache-commons-httpclient, androidhttpclient

`AndroidHttpClient` is [said to be thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103109/is-androidhttpclient-thread-safe). Just to make sure - does it means that I can use a single client instance in my app for all the HTTP requests?
Is there a reason not to do so?

In its source code, I noticed that it uses `BasicHttpContext` and not `SyncBasicHttpContext`. Does the `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` take care of all threading complexity?